# Cryptic error when dealing with functors in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am getting a very strange error when trying to implement fmap for one of my datatypes:
I have a datatype defined as follows:

```
newtype WarningAccumulator w a = WarningAccumulator (a,[w])
   deriving (Show,Eq)
```

Next I implemented the fmap function as follows:

```
instance Functor (WarningAccumulator w) where
   fmap :: (a -> b) -> WarningAccumulator w a -> WarningAccumulator w b
   fmap f (WarningAccumulator (list, value)) = WarningAccumulator(list, f value)
```

It gives me:

```
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘b’
  Expected: WarningAccumulator w b
    Actual: WarningAccumulator w a
```

It confuses me very much because f value would return type b not a, so I have no idea why this error occurs? Can someone explain to me why and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you get any other errors also? The issue that stands out to me is that you applied `f` to the second value of the pair instead of the first value, which has type `a`.

Comment: That is not the error I get at all; the errors I get are much less cryptic and together hint pretty strongly at the problem: "Couldn't match expected type ‘[w]’ with actual type ‘b’" and "Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘[w]’". Are you showing us the actual code you're getting that error from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting confused because your type parameters are in the order `w` `a`, while your constructor's fields are in the order `a` `[w]`. You do need the `a` type parameter to be last if that's what you want to fmap over, but the constructor's fields may be in any order. If it's not too wrong semantically, you might choose to reorder the fields so that you can remember how they match up to the type parameters. If you do that, your implementation of `fmap` will suddenly be correct.

Alternatively, you can leave the field order as it is, and swap the occurrences of `list` and `value` in your `fmap` implementation:

```
instance Functor (WarningAccumulator w) where
   fmap f (WarningAccumulator (value, list)) = WarningAccumulator(f value, list)
```